# Imagesearch Limit in functions?

Tags: autohotkey

I have been making a complicated bot, and I have hit a brick wall while trying to add any new features with imagesearch, Most of these searches require locating(Or not locating) a image. But now, every function I try to add just goes crazy, sometimes it will just run in a loop, unable to find a image, sometimes it will move to 778, 194 and just continue clicking as if every search was supposed to click at 778, 194. I'm sure it is something overly simple, I'm just going blind reading these chunks over and over again. 
Source code:

```
demand()
{
global img_battle
global img_battle2
global img_demand
global img_lolcheck
global img_lolmarket
global img_demandcontrol
global img_demandlower
global img_demandhigher
global img_demand2

ImageSearch, myszX, myszY, 1, 1, windowSizeX, windowSizeY, *10 %img_demand%
8:
if (ErrorLevel = 0) {
  4:
  MouseMove, 778, 194
  Sleep, 500
  ImageSearch, myszX, myszY, 1, 1, windowSizeX, windowSizeY, *10 %img_lolmarket%
  if (ErrorLevel = 0){
    MouseMove, myszX + 15, myszY + 2
    sleep, 500
    MouseClick, Left, 
    sleep, 500
    ImageSearch, myszX, myszY, 1, 1, windowSizeX, windowSizeY, *10 %img_lolcheck%
    if (ErrorLevel = 0) {
      sleep, 500
      5:
      ImageSearch, myszX, myszY, 1, 1, windowSizeX, windowSizeY, *10 %img_demandcontrol%
      if (ErrorLevel = 0) {
        MouseMove, myszX + 15, myszY + 2
        sleep, 500
        MouseClick, Left, 
        Sleep, 500
        ImageSearch, myszX, myszY, 1, 1, windowSizeX, windowSizeY, *10 %img_demandlower%
        if (ErrorLevel = 0) {
          MouseMove, myszX + 15, myszY + 2
          sleep, 500
          MouseClick, Left
          Sleep, 500
          6:
          MouseMove, 716, 197
          Sleep, 500
          ImageSearch, myszX, myszY, 1, 1, windowSizeX, windowSizeY, *10 %img_battle%
          if (ErrorLevel = 0){
            MouseMove, myszX +15, myszY +2
            Sleep, 500
            MouseClick,
            Sleep, 500
            ImageSearch, myszX, myszY, 1, 1, windowSizeX, windowSizeY, *10 %img_battle2%
            if (ErrorLevel = 1){
              goto, 6
                               }
                             }
                           }
      else{
        goto, 5
      }
                         }
                       }
      else {
        goto, 4
      }
                     }
                   }
else{
  ImageSearch, myszX, myszY, 1, 1, windowSizeX, windowSizeY, *10 %img_demand2%
  if (ErrorLevel = 1) {
    goto, 8
  }
}
}
```

Comment: It looks like you do not check your `ErrorLevel` after using `ImageSearch` under label `4`. Also, people are more inclined to help if you clean up the indentation/spacing of your code.  Right now it is barely readable.

Comment: @ElliotDeNolf
I wasn't, It probably happened within the few hours of error testing, however, now it is stuck back to just not finding the images. I cleaned up my code a bit, is this good? if not, please be specific on the formatting. Also; this might be of no use, but here is the log for my `demand()` function
`137: demand()  
285: ImageSearch,myszX,myszY,1,1,windowSizeX,windowSizeY,*10 %img_demand%
287: if (ErrorLevel = 0)  
339: ImageSearch,myszX,myszY,1,1,windowSizeX,windowSizeY,*10 %img_demand2%
340: if (ErrorLevel = 1)  
343: }
344: }`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need command `CoordMode` http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/CoordMode.htm
That command sets coordinate mode for various commands (including `ImageSearch` and `MouseMove` commands) to be relative to either the active window or the screen.
Add these two lines to beginning of file (before function call):

```
CoordMode, Pixel, Screen
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
```

First line will set coordinate mode for `ImageSearch` command and second line for `MouseMove` command relative to screen.